# Pandas group by to convert different rows to one row with array of values

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, dataframe

Suppose, we have next dataframe :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'animal': 'cat dog cat fish dog cat cat'.split(),
                  'size': list('SSMMMLL'),
                  'weight': [8, 10, 11, 1, 20, 12, 12],
                  'adult' : [False] * 5 + [True] * 2})

   adult animal size  weight
0  False    cat    S       8
1  False    dog    S      10
2  False    cat    M      11
3  False   fish    M       1
4  False    dog    M      20
5   True    cat    L      12
6   True    cat    L      12
```

And I want to convert it to the following form(denormalise it) by weights:

```
         weights
animal                 
cat     [8, 11, 12, 12]
dog            [10, 20]
fish                [1]
```

Currently, I use the following code :

```
df.groupby('animal',as_index=True).apply(lambda sf : pd.Series([list(sf['weight'])]
,index=['weights']))
```

but I wonder if there exists a clear way to do this

Answer (score 5):

This is just slightly shorter that the way you do it but i guess you can do :

```
In [22]: df.groupby('animal')['weight'].apply(list)
Out[22]: 
animal
cat     [8, 11, 12, 12]
dog            [10, 20]
fish                [1]
Name: weight, dtype: object
```

or

```
In [40]: df.groupby('animal')['weight'].apply(list).to_frame()
Out[40]: 
                 weight
animal                 
cat     [8, 11, 12, 12]
dog            [10, 20]
fish                [1]
```

The fisrt output a `Series` and the second a `DataFrame`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, though I also want second column to have a 'name' weights.